# How to verify an SCCM action has completed via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

The code below is used to trigger the SCCM action 'SoftwareUpdateScan' cycle:

```
$CimMethodParameters = @{
  Namespace  = 'ROOT\ccm'
  Class      = 'SMS_CLIENT'
  MethodName = 'TriggerSchedule'
}

Invoke-CimMethod @CimMethodParameters -Arguments @{sScheduleID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000113}' }
```

After the above code is run, I do not know how to determine the following:

1. That the action was successfully started?
2. When the action completes?
3. Was the action completed successfully or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a function for each action that incorporates the verification of completion or failure of the action.

https://github.com/MicksITBlogs/PowerShell/blob/master/SCCMActions.ps1